# Accessing CSS variables via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-variables

How do you get css variables in jquery? I'm trying to replace `border: 2px solid #fff` with the css variable --border.

Here is my code:

```
$(".header .navigation").on("show.bs.collapse", function(e) {
  console.log("open")
  $(".navigation").css("border", "2px solid #fff");
});
```

Comment: `$(".navigation").removeAttr('style');` just removes any inline style(removes attribute)

Comment: That's only when navigation is closing.

Comment: The reverse is `$(".navigation").attr("border", "2px solid #fff");`, I believe.

Comment: This is not what I'm asking. I want to do it with css variable which in this case is --border.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I edited it.

Comment: Roll on year 2020 when we don't need to support IE11.  (no support for css variables in IE11)

Comment: I don't care about IE anymore tbh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method to get all styles and get CSS variable value from it using [getPropertyValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue) method.

```
$(".header .navigation").on("show.bs.collapse", function(e) {
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
  $(".navigation").css("border", style.getPropertyValue('--border'));
});
```

If you want to update the variable via Javascript then you can use [`setPropertyValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setPropertyValue) method.

```
$(".header .navigation").on("show.bs.collapse", function(e) {
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
  style.setPropertyValue('--border', '2px solid #f00');
});
```

---

Or you can use CSS [`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var) for referring a variable through CSS.

```
$(".header .navigation").on("show.bs.collapse", function(e) {
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
  $(".navigation").css("border", "var(--border)"));
});
```

Comment: This is working but do i use this or $(".navigation").css("border", "var(--border)");? Which one is better?

Comment: @doublet2 :  `var(--border)` would be better since you don't want the value for other purpose in JS

Comment: Another answer suggests how to change the value for `--border`, so if you use `var(--border)` it will (should?) change if you change `--border` later.

Comment: @freedomn-m : yes it will

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, you can set the border of your navigation to be equal to `var(--border)`. Then, within your javascript, you can change the value of your `--border` variable using `$('body').get(0).style.setProperty("--border", "style");`

See example below:

```js
const bodyStyle = $('body').get(0).style;
$(".header .navigation").on("mouseenter", function(e) {
  bodyStyle.setProperty("--border", "2px solid #f00");
})
.on("mouseleave", function(e) {
  bodyStyle.setProperty("--border", "0px solid #f00");
});
```

```css
.header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.navigation {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  border: var(--border);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">
  <nav class="navigation">
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.css("border-color", "var(--border)");
```

Example:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    $("div").css("border-color", "var(--border)");
}, 1000);
```

```css
:root {
  --border: red;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```